# JQuery on change make ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bunch of selects as filters like this

```
<select name="color" data-options="katalog.php?cat=3" class="filter">
    <option value="1">White</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
</select>
```

but in Firebug I get an error and can't figure out why

```
$('body').on("change", '.filter', function() {

    $('#mainstage').load($(this).data('options') + '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).attr('value'));
})
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: something in jquery itself 
 

...[c]):this.attr(c,b[c]);return this}if(d=y.getElementById(c[2]),d&&d.parentNode){...

Comment: @Michael was does the error message itself say?

Comment: @empiric I don't know this is the line I get in the console of course the bug is in my code not in jquery library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url you are requesting is `"katalog.php?cat=3&color=undefined"` because you should not be using `attr()` to read the value. Use jQuery's `val()` method so you get the value of the option that was selected.

```
... '=' + $(this).val())
```

Comment: I changed it like you suggested but error is still the same :(

Comment: I think the error is with something else. My guess it is having an issue with whatever you are returning from the Ajax call.

Comment: The error occurs when I load the page. When jquery bind the event I think I don't touch the select so no event is fired. The page however is loaded by ajax too.

Comment: @espascarello sorry it works now, I only saw that I still get this error now I see the ajax request is made. But now I don't know what to do with this error I know I indroduce this with my event handler but how?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs at `$(this).attr('value')` , which is trying to grab the value attribute of the select element itself instead of getting the **selected value** . Just find the selected text or value .

**Example :**

Finding the text value of the selected option via `$(this).find(":selected").text()`

```
$('body').on("change", 'select', function() {

     $('#mainstage').load($(this).data('options') + '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).find(":selected").text());

})
```

**Example:**

Grabbing the value attribute of selected option via `$(this).val()`

```
$('body').on("change", 'select', function() {

   $('#mainstage').load($(this).data('options') + '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val());

})
```

Hope this helps